# Unity Input Field Lock previously typed characters after a time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I've been messing around with a word game in Unity C# and have come to a standstill regarding an anti-cheat mechanic I want to implement.

Once the first letter has been entered into the input field, I start running a 2 second timer. After the 2 seconds, in the player does not submit or type another letter, the input field should lock the previously typed letters in place on the input field and any letters typed after should be typed after it.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
currTime = 0;
hasInput = false;
lockedString = "";

void Update(){
    if(hasInput){
        currTime += Time.deltaTime * 1;
        if(currTime >= 2){
            //Stores current string value of input field
            lockedString = inputField.text;
        }
    }
}

void OnInputValueChange(){
    currTime = 0;
    hasInput = true;
    if(lockedString != ""){
    inputField.text = lockedString + inputField.text;
    }
}
```

Right now I'm running `OnInputValueChange()` whenever the input field's value is changed. I also manage to store the string that's been entered so far once the timer hits 2 seconds, but I do not know how to make it so that the input field "locks" the locked string into the front and allow changes to the letters typed behind it. The code `inputField.text = lockedString + inputField.text;` simply adds the `lockedString` variable to the input field every time the value gets changed.

The desired outcome is as such in pseudo-code:

```
//User types "bu"
//2 second timer starts
//During these 2 seconds, user can delete "bu" or continue typing
//User deletes "bu" and types "ah"
//Once the 2 second timer ends, whatever string is now in input is locked
//"ah" is now locked at the front of the input field
//After locking "ah", user cannot delete it anymore, but can continue typing
```

Any insight to how I might achieve something like this will be most helpful. Thanks for taking the time to help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are simply concatenating the string. You will want to check if the string starts with the same characters, and if not, completely overwrite the input:

```
void Update() {
    if (hasInput && ((Time.time - inputTime) > 2f))
    {
        //Stores current string value of input field
        lockedString = inputField.text;
        hasInput = false;
    }
}

void OnInputValueChange() {
    inputTime = Time.time;
    hasInput = true;
    if ((lockedString.Length > 0) && (inputField.text.IndexOf(lockedString) != 0)) {
        // Replace invalid string
        inputField.text = lockedString;
        // Update cursor position
        inputField.MoveTextEnd(false);
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have implemented an alternate method of measuring the time passed. Feel free to replace this with your own method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll test this out as soon as I'm home!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks. If I may ask another follow up question, right now, the input field locks the players input nicely, but when I tried to delete letters, the cursor moves back without changing the string. Is there a way to make sure the cursor always stays ahead of the locked string?

Thanks so much, +1.

Comment: Looking into it atm... i'm not seeing a whole lot of solutions

Comment: I believe you are looking for `inputField.MoveTextEnd(false);`

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the caret position update